# Realtime updates for listings in web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, signalr

I've got an asp.net mvc based SPA web application. It's basically built up of a lot of listing -> details combinations. I'm wanting to know if there is a way to use SignalR to have realtime updates of the listings that the end user is viewing?

Scenario, there are 3 users. User 1 is viewing a list of orders in the system and user 2 is viewing a list of customers. User 3 updates an order, signalR tells application there has been an order update and the order listing user 1 is viewing is updated to the latest data. User 3 does the same thing with a customers data and the system updates user 2's listing accordingly.

Just wondering if this is doable and what is the best approach. The application is using WebApi to pull the data for the listings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look this demo using knockout and signalr
https://github.com/turanuk/signalrgrid